# Mathematics Based Sorted Insert

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insert

Given a sorted array, I believe an equation can be created to determine the index where any given number would be inserted.

For instance, given the sorted array of [ -1, 0, 1 ], there is an input/output table for my desired function like this:

```
 x  | f(x)
----------
-2  | 0
-1.5| 0
-1  | 0, 1
-0.5| 1
 0  | 1, 2
 0.5| 2
 1  | 2, 3
 1.5| 3
 2  | 3
```

I have chosen to use x as the number I wish to insert into the array, and the function would output the indices that an insert function could use to insert x into the array sorted.

What interests me is that given this simplification of the problem, I notice two things:

- The output of the function must be an integer
- There are cases where the function could return 2 different values

And this is where I leave my thoughts to those who have more experience than me...

My first thought is that the output reminds me of Karnaugh mapping. There are two values the output can be in cases, but it doesn't matter which result is chosen.

My second thought is of quantum computing. I am not experienced enough to be specific, but if two functional outputs can be mapped to the qubit and processed quantumly, what opportunities does that hold in such a context? Could a quantum computer help derive this formula I'm looking for?

My example is very simple, but I just wanted to share this here in case anyone was interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial of degree `n` can be uniquely defined by `n+1` points. However, you'll want a polynomial that can be fit to your `n+1` points, while remaining monotonic. I'm not entirely certain how to accomplish this, but I'm sure that curve fitting libraries have already solved it for us. It probably just means adding a few more degrees of freedom to the polynomial, and minimizing some constraints.

Regarding your note on superpositioning- I doubt it has many implications for the world of quantum computing. Actually, I would argue that `F` shouldn't map to more than one value- as that would violate the definition of a function. If there are two indices it could map to, its because the values are equal, and hence order doesn't matter, so you should just pick one (insert before, or insert after an equal value) as you'd have to do in the implementation anyways.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the choice of index is so trivial, I couldn't imagine needing to waste quantum power on it. I was up too late last night, but thanks for your answer.